# How to check RSA version on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, security, rsa

Please help me finding what is RSA version on security framework on iOS 11?
Our customer want to know it but I don't know how to find out it.

Comment: The question needs to be improved, it is to vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean for Trusted Root Certificates.

You could just share this with the customer, maybe they know better as to what they are looking for.

[List of available trusted root certificates in iOS 11](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208125)

EDIT :

The particular concern of the customer is the vulnerability discovered in the Infineon RSA library 1.02.013.
This library is used in the Infineon Trusted Platform Module (TPM).

> Trusted Platform Module (TPM) is an international standard for a secure cryptoprocessors that can securely store critical data such as passwords, certificates and encryption keys. TPM is a dedicated microcontroller designed to secure hardware by integrating cryptographic keys into devices and is used for secured crypto processes within computing devices as well as for secured storage of critical data. TPMs are typically used in business laptops, routers and embedded and IoT devices.

Fortunately **iOS does not use the Infineon RSA library for security**. Your customer can rest assured that it is not vulnerable to this particular flaw.

Read [this](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/10/crypto-failure-cripples-millions-of-high-security-keys-750k-estonian-ids/) TechCrunch post for more info on the vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but 
depend on this : 
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-15361 
So they want us show what is current RSA version that we're using for encrypt / decrypt data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, it clarifies your concern. I think iOS has never had this particular vulnerability so you customer can rest assured. Read my edit for more info on this. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the requested information is in the FIPS140 certifications, see:

[Apple iOS CoreCrypto Module v7.0](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Module-Validation-Program/Certificate/2828) and [Apple iOS CoreCrypto Kernel Module v7.0](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Module-Validation-Program/Certificate/2828).

A full list of [Apple FIPS 140 Module Validations](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Module-Validation-Program/Validated-Modules/Search)

For more information consider using a developer support incident or the [Apple security mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/security-announce).